# IF condition in Windows 2008

Tags: windows, cmd, clearcase

I'm trying to run the below If condition but I'm not receiving any result.

```
IF %config%=="Yes" goto :findmerge
goto :endscript
:findmerge
cd M:\%viewname%\%vobname%
set /p branchname=Enter Branch Name:
set /p labelname=Enter Branch Name:
cleartool findmerge . -nc -fver .../%branchname%/%labelname% -print

:endscript
echo "Set Config Spec to Main/LATEST"
```

What could be the problem with this block?

Comment: Try: `if /I "%config%"=="Yes" goto :findmerge`

Comment: Thank you! It's working.

Comment: How can put an else condition in windows?

Comment: You need to accept the solution provided which would help for future readers

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[string comparison in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955571/6309)", adding double-quotes around the environment variable is needed here (as [Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513264/if-condition-in-windows-2008#comment52886091_32513264)).

> How can put an else condition in windows?

In your, you already have a "else":

```
IF /I "%config%"=="Yes" goto :findmerge
goto :endscript
```

That means `if ... then findmerge else endscript`.

The other technique, as shown in "[if/then/else statements in Windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11849558/6309)" is using `()`

```
if xxx (
  ...
) else (
  ...
)
```